# How to evaluate and generate a result from a html form using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

as the title says i need to create a game but my problem is that I don't know how to read the radio buttons using javascript and based on the options, it generates a scenario with the game mode with the difficulty the player picks. I am using one text input for the nickname and 2 fieldsets like this one for the player to select the type of the game and difficulty.

```
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Dificuldade:</legend>
                    <input type="radio" name="dificuldade" value="easy"> easy </input>
                    <input type="radio" name="dificuldade" value="medium"> medium </input>
                    <input type="radio" name="dificuldade" value="hard"> hard </input>
            </fieldset>
```

Comment: We're going to need more details on how the form is sent and evaluated. Plus any information that would hinder a form from sending. Try to change the title to a specific problem and not a subject area?

Comment: That's my problem i don't know how do I send the form and evaluate it using javascript so it can generate a scenario

Comment: There are a couple of different ways ajax, post, submit, json... I would go with something simple with javascript forms first. W3Schools is a great place for javascript tutorials and for forms you can even check this out: http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptform.php

Comment: Hey, i will definitely check that out, i should of said on the post but i can only use html+css+javascript and probably a bit of jquery on this work

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use jQuery, it makes life so much easier:

```
$('[name=dificuldade]:checked').val()
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3bc9m/

Otherwise you would have to go through each of the radio buttons in the DOM, and check their `checked` property.  When you find the one with `checked === true`, you can then read its `value` property.  Like this:

```
var fieldset = document.getElementById('difficuldade'); // You'd need to set an ID to the fieldset element
var curr = fieldset.firstChild;

while (curr != null) {
    if (curr.checked) {
        break;
    }
    curr = curr.nextSibling;
}

curr.value; // This is your selected value
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3bc9m/1/

As Nate mentioned, make sure the DOM is ready, otherwise this will not work.  This means that all of your code should be run on the `onload` event of the `body` element.  See this for more details: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_body_onload.asp

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering, i think I have tried the 2nd method you said and used an alert at the end of the for cycle to see what it saved, but it didn't return anything

Comment: I made an edit to demonstrate how you would achieve this with vanilla Javascript.  Do consider learning jQuery though, you can see how much pain it saves you.

Comment: Sorry i didn't came be earlier, but it was really late already here. I have another question, what do you mean by making sure DOM is ready too?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3bc9m/11/ I inserted my form on jsfiddle and tried to modify your function so it can validate my 2 fieldset , but it seems like it isn't working, what am i doing wrong? And how i can i store the username since i will only use it when I am printing the results

Comment: I corrected some of your mistakes in the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3bc9m/45/. There were a few typos, and you were missing the id="output" and id="output1" elements.  However, to clean things up a bit, you should really create a method that takes a fieldset id and returns the selected radio button that lies within it.  
As far as storing the username goes, look into the localStorage object: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp